# WSL2/Mongodb: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 on Windows

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am coding along a tutorial and I am stuck at connecting MongoDB to Express. I successfully installed MongoDB (Mongo Compass and Mongo shell) and I was able to play around with it a little bit to familiarize myself with it. I am using a Windows 10 computer. I was able to create a database and add some documents and collections to it via the mongo shell and cmd prompt.

For the React app I am building, I am using VS Code as the IDE. VS Code is running on Ubuntu (WSL 2) and I cannot connect my app to the database. I have even tried using the MongoDB VS Code extension, but I still cannot connect to the databases available on compass. The Atlas clusters seem to connect just fine.

Below I am including screen grabs of the VS Code and Compass in case someone notices something off.
[image: vs code]  [image: compass]

Here is the code where I try the connection. I have tested out the output on postman, but I am not getting any output in return. The server is running according to nodemon and the app crashes every time I run the get command on postman.

```
import express from "express";
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb"; //connects to the db

const app = express();
app.use(express.json()); // middleware to enable posting json

app.get('/api/articles/:name', async (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.params;
  const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017');
  await client.connect();

  const db = client.db('react-blog-db');

  const article = await db.collection('articles').findOne({ name });
  res.json(article);
});
```

I have tried some of the options highlighted [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5486), but none of them work for me.

Comment: Did you start the MongoDB?

Comment: Hey @WernfriedDomscheit, yes, MongoDB is up and running. I just tested it out in the cmd prompt, and I am able to access the databases.

Comment: `localhost` can mean either `::1` or `127.0.01`, if you use the IP address instead of localhost does it behave differently?

Comment: @TeddyDavidson did you manage to resolve this? If so please share your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use morgan and mongoose for mongoDB, I know when using mongoose you have to specify the database in your URL string, I would try

```
 new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/thedatabaseyouwanttoconnectto')
```

Comment: someone else also suggested using localhost instead of the IP address, I think that's a good idea, new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/databasename');

Comment: Hi @Danielle W thank you for your input. I tried that, but the problem was still persistent. I'll continue to try different combinations of the solutions suggested until one sticks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your IPv4 address.

> mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017

will become.

> mongodb://192.168.100.5:27017

note that "192.168.100.5" will be different for you. You can get it using ipconfig command in cmd.

Comment: Hi @Muhib Ahmed thank you for your input. I tried that, but the problem was still persistent. I'll keep trying different options.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the solutions suggested do not work for the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2). However, switching the IDE environment to the local computer, switching

```
 const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017');
```

to

```
 const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017');
```

solved the database connection issue.